# Creating an icon by mixing existing icons

Tags: mobile, icons, ios, design

I'm trying to design an icon which will be mixed of two different icons. for example, a camera icon and video icon together in one single icon.

Are there any design principles, ideas or links for references how to mix icons? I couldn't find any on google search.

Comment: try looking here: http://iconmonstr.com/

Comment: what ideas about icons are you asking for, exactly??

Comment: umm.. like how can I create an icon with two icons mixed. like half of each icon, something like that. I haven't seen an icon designed like that yet, so just wanna get a basic idea, or if there's any design principle that I need to follow. thanks @Aprillion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when talking about icons, the UX design principles focus on creating / choosing the right icon for a given use case, not how the icon is created (whether or not it is mergerd / combined / mixed from 2 existing icons or created from scratch), see e.g. http://boxesandarrows.com/optimizing-ui-icons-for-faster-recognition/

though you can try to search for **[overlay two icons](https://www.google.cz/search?q=overlay+two+icons)** instead of "mix", e.g.:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20353907/how-to-stack-overlap-more-than-2-icons-in-font-awesome
- http://www.iconjoiner.com/
- https://icons8.com/articles/effects-for-icons/

if you want to know how to combine 2 images, see tutorials about **layers** in graphics software, e.g. https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/5398/how-to-create-two-layers-in-gimp-and-merge-them-back-into-one